# Finding a dual basis for the vector space of polynomials degree less than or equal to 2

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the vector space of real polynomials of degree less or equal to 2. Consider the functionals

$X_1(f(t))=\int_0^1f(t)dt$

$X_2(f(t)) = f'(1)$

$X_3(f(t)) = f(0)$

Identifying $V$ and $V''$, find the dual basis for ${X_1,X_2,X_3}$

I know what a dual basis is but I can't work out how to begin finding this one so could anyone help me out please

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$ be the basis of $V$ dual to $\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}$, i.e.

$$X_i(f_j)=\delta_{ij}. $$

Let us find $f_1,f_2,f_3$.  By definition, $f_i=a_i+b_it+c_it^2$. Then

$$1\stackrel{!}{=}X_1(f_1)=a_1+\frac{b_1}{2}+\frac{c_1}{3}$$
$$0\stackrel{!}{=}X_2(f_1)=b_1+2c_1 $$
$$0\stackrel{!}{=}X_3(f_1)=a_1$$

which implies $a_1=0$, $b_1=3$ and $c_1=-\frac{3}{2}$, i.e. $f_1(t)=3t-\frac{3}{2}t^2$.

Similar computations lead to $f_2$ and $f_3$, by solving

$$X_1(f_2)=X_3(f_2)=X_1(f_3)=X_2(f_3)=0,$$

and

$$X_2(f_2)=X_3(f_3)=1. $$